# Blender and texture problem during the exporting phase

Tags: uv, shaders, export, unity

I created a library on blender and assigned a simple shader that recreates the wood.
[image]

I did the UV Unwrapping of it with the automatic tool called "Smart UV Project".
[image]

As you can see the texture is in black and white and I don't understand why.

If I try to export the library and import it into Unity it appears completely clear and the wood shader is completely lost.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

[image]

I have the same problem with Blender 3.9 or Blender 4.0

Comment: Hello and welcome. Blender shader nodes are not supported by unity, you have to UV unwrap, bake your materials to a texture and export that to unity

Comment: This will explain @Emir's comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: UV unwrapping, by whatever method, creates a correspondence between the surface of your object and locations in 2D UV space, applicable to any texture you throw at it. It does not store the texture itself. You have to provide that. Unity will expect an image, which you can [bake](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/baking.html) from your procedural material